# Writing multiple class attributes into a single row in CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a list of books called **bookList**

In this list, there are **books**

Each book has many attributes such as **bookTitle, author, quantity, and isbn**.

My program starts by reading a csv file, which has 5 rows, each row has comma seperated values starting with the name of the bookTitle all the way to the end of that row, being retail price.

Reading the file is no issue, but my problem is in my program you can manipulate the book's data, such as changing the title name.

How can I efficiently write back into the file with the changes made/added books/deleted books?

**I tried this**:

```
with open('inventory.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator = '\n')
        for book in bookList:
            writer.writerow(book.bookTitle, book.isbn, book.author, book.publisher, book.dateAdded, book.quantity, book.retail, book.wholesale)
```

But "writerow" only takes 1 argument (8 were given)

**How can I write into the csv file multiple things per row, separated by commas, for each attribute my book has?**

Comment: Simples, just enclose in a list. `writer.writerow([book.bookTitle, book.isbn, book.author, book.publisher, book.dateAdded, book.quantity, book.retail, book.wholesale])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentaion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects), the `write` method takes a single row as its input argument. All you need to do is turn your attributes into `list`. I.e.

```
with open('inventory.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator = '\n')
    for book in bookList:
        writer.writerow([book.bookTitle, book.isbn, book.author,
                         book.publisher, book.dateAdded, book.quantity, 
                         book.retail, book.wholesale])
```

Comment: I could've sworn this made my csv file blank before, but it's working fine. Does it matter if it's a list/tuple?

Comment: @DeathPox AFAIK it just requires a sequence that can be iterated. Try it.

Comment: @DeathPox I find list more natural for this because that's what you'll get if you read CSVs.